# stuck with ruby and mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a hash in which mysql column is related to key of hash and value is related to value of hash

```
 {:jobID=>"1", :checkoutArtificateFolder=>"/cmf/new/build/Artifacts/factory-config.xml"}
```

now this is my code by the help of this I am inserting data into table 
here

```
def write_data      
    $db_obj = # a data base object 
    table_name = table_name
    jobID = jobID
    hash_data = hash_data       


    insert = "INSERT INTO #{table_name} ("
    data = ""


    hash_data.each do|key,value|

        insert = "#{insert}" + " #{ key},"
        data = "#{data}" + "'#{ value}',"
    end


    insert = insert.chop
    data = data.chop

    query = insert + ")" + "VALUES"  + "(#{data})"
    exec = $db_obj.prepare(query)
    exec.execute

end
```

but in database this value ("/cmf/new/build/Artifacts/factory-config.xml") is convert into this ("/cmf/new/build/Artifacts/factory-config.")

can anyone help me and tell me why this is happening and how I can correct this ?

Comment: Your code is not good, but should work. Check other possible reasons. `/cmf/new/build/Artifacts/factory-config.` is exactly 40 characters, so I would check mysql varchar length

Comment: Ok cool and what should i do to make this code better.

Comment: learn! See [web developer evolution](http://dev.hubspot.com/bid/85467/Evolution-of-a-Web-Developer-From-PHP-Newbie-To-Python-Ninja) and #18 point. You can use ActiveRecord without Rails instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using varchar type with maximum 40 chars for the field checkoutArtificateFolder. Either increase the size or change the field type to text.

And why can't you use ActiveRecord or Datamapper for database operations which makes your life easier?